Could anyone tell me how to know the amount of our admob impression?
I want to know how to see my admob impression amount.
I have searched on google but i couldn't find what I want. Could anyone here tell me the steps to see the impression amount of our admob ads. I hope I would be able to know. Thankyou

goto https://apps.admob.com/v2/home.
look for Impr. and you will find the impression count. for more detailed info click on view report

